# Using getSpans method to get all spans in a spannable

Tags: java, android, spannablestring, spannable, spannablestringbuilder

I use the following code to get all spans in a spannable string.

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(editText.getText());
Object [] objectSpans = str.getSpans(0, str.length(), Object.class);

//loop through all spans
for (Object objSpan: objectSpans) {
   Spanned spanned = (Spanned) objSpan;// Here I encounter a ClassCastException
   start = spanned.getSpanStart(new Object());
   end = spanned.getSpanEnd(new Object());
   ...
}
```

I encounter a following ClassCastException when I want to cast objSpan to Spanned (in line 6).

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.style.SpellCheckSpan cannot
>   be cast to android.text.Spanned

How can I solve this problem? Is there a better way to get all spans in a spannable string?

Comment: Any updates on this? Shall I improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `instanceof` instead doing the casting automatically.

```
for (Object objSpan: objectSpans) {
   if(objSpan instanceof Spanned){
    Spanned spanned = (Spanned) objSpan;// Here I encounter a ClassCastException
    start = spanned.getSpanStart(new Object());
    end = spanned.getSpanEnd(new Object());
    ...
   } 
}
```

To understand what's the problem you may read this [`ClassCastException Documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) so you can read :

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:

So, if you want to do a `cast` you have to make sure that object is the same type of what your are declaring, otherwise you'll get a `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 0):

check if objSpan is instance of Spanned.. Seems like @Skizo thinks so as mine.therefore sorry for the repeated answer but it solved my problem too.

```
SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder(editText.getText());
Object [] objectSpans = str.getSpans(0, str.length(), Object.class);

//loop through all spans
for (Object objSpan: objectSpans) {
   if(objSpan instanceof Spanned){
   Spanned spanned = (Spanned) objSpan;// Here I encounter a ClassCastException
   start = spanned.getSpanStart(new Object());
   end = spanned.getSpanEnd(new Object());
   ...
}
}
```